# Morphological dictionary

Tags: discussion, online-resources, resource-request

I was wondering whether you knew of an online dictionary where you could find a word and other words derived from it. 
Like, for instance, "passion", "passionate" "passionately" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/) is pretty good for that.

For instance, after querying `passion*` and then clicking the `Common words` link in the result, it returns this:

> 1. passion
>   2. passional
>   3. passionary
>   4. passionate
>   5. passionately
>   6. passionateness
>   7. passionflower
>   8. passionist
>   9. passionless
>   10. passions
>   11. passiontide

Comment: Thank you for sharing such an amazing free service!

Comment: I have only one "complain": it's great for showing suffixes but useless when it comes to prefixes. If I look for engage* I won't find disengage. And if I look for list* I get "listen" in the results.

Comment: Other than that it's a cool tool! Thank you.

Comment: @user86782 You just need to put the asterisk at the front if you want prefixes: \*engage. (And \*engage\* will give you both *disengage* and *engagedly*.) I'm also not sure why you think that list\* should *not* give you listen.